# Signing an assembly in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net-assembly, signing, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to write a simple console app in Visual Studio 2022 and then debug it. This would be so simple but the IT dept here have added a group policy that all applications must be digitally signed before they can be executed.

How can I sign the compiled executable file in order to run it in the VS debugger? I have a PFX certificate file but nothing I've tried seems to add a signature to the file properties in the exe file in the bin folder.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried:

- Installing the certificate which was successful.
- Generating a strong name snk file and ticking the option to sign the assembly which was successful.
- Running the signtool in PS to apply the certificate which failed.

I would like to sign the executable as part of the build process in order to hit F5 and debug as normal.

Comment: same problem.  Had to check "delay sign only" option and sign at command line